# What do W and U notate in a GRU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I'm trying to figure out how to backpropagate a GRU Recurrent network, but I'm having trouble understanding the GRU architecture precisely.

The image below shows a GRU cell with 3 neural networks, receiving the concatenated previous hidden state and the input vector as its input.

[GRU example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd7Qb.png)

This image used I referenced for backpropagation, however, shows the inputs being forwarded into W and U for each of the gates, added, and then having their appropriate activation functions applied.

[GRU Backpropagation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxy8d.png)

the equation for the update gate shown on wikipedia is as shown here as an example

> zt = sigmoid((W(z)x*t* + U(z)h*t-1*))

can somebody explain to me what W and U represent?

EDIT:

in most of the sources I found, W and U are usually referred to as "weights", so my best guess is that W and U represent their own neural networks, but this would contradict the image I found before.

if somebody could give an example of how W and U would work in a simple GRU, that would be helpful.

Sources for the images: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/vignettes/GRU_units.html
https://towardsdatascience.com/animated-rnn-lstm-and-gru-ef124d06cf45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`W` and `U` are matrices whose values are learnt during training (a.k.a. neural network weights). The matrix `W` multiplies the vector `xt` and produces a new vector. Similarly, the matrix U multiplies the vector `ht-1` and produces a new vector. Those two new vectors are added together and then each component of the result is passed to the `sigmoid` function.